# What do you think is happening to my QGIS Georeferencer

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I'm pretty new with QGis, but have used tools as Openlayers and Geoserver for some years now without never being asked to diplay a georeferenced raster image. Which gets me to use QGis in order to build a Geotiff from a simple scanned PNG or JPEG.

I've followed many tutorials, but I'm somehow still struggling to import any image file in my Georeferencer plugin window.

Here's what I get when I import a jpeg image:

[image]

It looks like a badly read jpeg. Any idea ?

Thanks for your help !

**EDIT**

I've tried with a PNG by converting the original jpeg with an image tool (like IrfanView) and the image is now diplayed.
It's better, but doesn't answer exactly why the jpegs aren't working ...